# How to deal with excessive audio latency

Tags: audio, video, hdmi, bluetooth

My audio latency is excessive. The discrepancy between video (through HDMI) and sound is like 1000 ms.

I'm using bluetooth that fires to wireless omni 10 speaker.

The only way I know to reduce latency is to use my HDMI for both sound and video. But that means I've got to use my projectors' speakers whose sound isn't that awesome.

For movies, I can just compensate for this problem by setting -1000 ms latency. However, for video games the latency is unbearable.

What should I do?

I tried using 3.5 mm cable. If the cable is short, the latency is 400ms.

Actually I really wish my computer can connect to OMNI 10 using Wi-Fi straight from the computer.

They have Mac app but not a PC app. That's the problem.

I used google comcast audio. The result is the delay increase to 3500 ms.

Some said omni 10 has built in audio delay. Is it true?

Comment: I used google chromecast audio and the delay is still big.

Answer (score 2):

I would wager that Bluetooth is going to be the major contributing factor in the latency that you are experiencing. When considering Bluetooth products, look for those that support [aptX Low Latency](http://www.csr.com/products/aptx-low-latency) for speakers, or [aptX Live](http://www.csr.com/products/59/aptx-live) for headsets and other recording equipment. These are compression methods designed for reducing the latency over Bluetooth, although they will still have a minor delay due to the wireless nature of Bluetooth. The major downside here being that the manufacturers need to license this technology, meaning that not all products with support it, and products will likely be a tad more expensive. You also need to ensure that both the transmitter and receiver support the technology, adding potentially two things you would need to purchase. However wireless is always going to have massive latency compared to a line running to your speaker, so I cannot recommend it as the best solution.

Since you are not experiencing any issues with HDMI output, it might be best to consider picking up an audio receiver that can split the video and audio. Even my basic receiver is capable of receiving HDMI, outputting HDMI to my television, and splitting the audio to either my speakers or headset. Paired with a cheap 25ft 3.5mm extension cable, it has been by far the best solution for switching between my headphones, speaker system, or my TV's audio output with virtually no audio delay.

Comment: I tried that solution. The thing is there is a significant distance between my projector and the latency is also 1000 ms. I can connect the computer with my OMNI 10 speakers with short 1m 3.5 mm and I got 400 ms latency

Comment: @jimthio Probably clarifying information you might want to add to your question. If there's anything else you've tried or behavior you've noticed, do consider adding it also. I will revise my answer tomorrow when I can think straight :)

Comment: Omni 10 doesn't support aptx. I wonder if I can fix that using some bluetooth to 3.5mm dongle?